# Paste strings based on repeating logical vector elements

Tags: r

I have a vector of strings

```
vec <- c("apple", "banana", "plum", "cherry", "cake", "ginger")
```

and I have a corresponding logical vector

```
lvec <- c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)
```

I want to paste (paste0) the elements where I have sequences of FALSE's (or TRUE's).

Desired output:

```
c("apple", "banana", "plum", "cherrycake", "ginger")
```

Comment: But "banana" is set to FALSE. Why is it there?

Comment: Could try `tapply(x, data.table::rleid(y), paste, collapse = "")` (where `x <- c("apple", "banana", "plum", "cherry", "cake", "ginger")` and `y <- c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I first use `rle` and then modify the 'values' to be able to easily split the data into the desired groups. Then using *apply we can use paste with the desired parameters.

```
x <- c("apple", "banana", "plum", "cherry", "cake", "ginger")
y <- c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)
r <- rle(y)
r$values <- seq_along(r$values)
sapply(split(x, inverse.rle(r)), paste, collapse = "")
# alternatively but I didn't initially think of tapply
tapply(x, inverse.rle(r), paste, collapse = "")
```

which gives

```
> sapply(split(x, inverse.rle(r)), paste, collapse = "")
           1            2            3            4            5 
     "apple"     "banana"       "plum" "cherrycake"     "ginger"
```

Answer (score 1):

With `tapply`, you could do

```
tapply(vec, cumsum(c(1, diff(lvec) != 0)), FUN=function(x) paste(x, collapse=""))
       1            2            3            4            5 
 "apple"     "banana"       "plum" "cherrycake"     "ginger"
```

The groups are calculated using `diff` on the logical vector and checking if it changes, these changes are cumulatively summed. Then, the resulting groups are pasted together.

**data**

```
vec <- c("apple", "banana", "plum", "cherry", "cake", "ginger")
lvec <- c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `rleid` from the data.table package.  The `unname` is optional -- if it is omitted then the names will be sequence numbers.

```
library(data.table)
unname(tapply(x, rleid(y), paste, collapse = ""))
```

giving:

```
[1] "apple"      "banana"     "plum"       "cherrycake" "ginger"
```